# Javascript not linking properly with node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Using Node/Express/EJS and I havent included any js files yet, well im starting to and cannot get my `alert("working");` to work! Ironic huh.

The goal is to get learnJs.js to load in the browser to show the alert so I know things are working.

Here is node including the directory:

```
// Static Resource Inclusions
app.use(express.static(__dirname +"/styles"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +"/img"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +"/js"));
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

Here is the file structure I have:

[[image]

Here is the learnJs.js:

[image]

Here is the front end template, `header.ejs` and it gets called on every page:

```
<head>
<title>Memento</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts/learnJs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the path of `js` file in browser?

Comment: Im not sure I follow, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load script like below , **/js/** is not required

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/learnJs.js"></script>
```

Comment: You win! I already told it to go to /js so I dont need to do that again in the script tag, because its then looking for `/js/js/scripts/learnJs.js`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `learnJs` file has been loaded into your browser by checking the `developer console` in the browser.

Comment: It gets my 404 response

Comment: So your `express` app doesn't response the file